# How can i convert my PHP Table into XL sheet format

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table and performed some arithmetic operations on that using PHP. After the calculations, all the values are stored in the table. How can I convert my PHP page table into an XL sheet format?

Comment: Show the codes what you've tried. Research + try first, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve it would be exporting your table in .csv format.

[Documentation function.fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php)

```
$dataset = array(
  array('Name', 'Phone', 'Country'),
  array('Maria', '+555199999999', 'Brazil'),
  array('João', '+555188888888', 'Brazil')
);

$fp = fopen ('catalog.csv', 'w');

foreach ($dataset as $data) {
  fputcsv ($fp, $data);
}

fclose ($fp);
```

But ... if XLS is really necessary. This tool can give you a little help.

[Documentation of Tool](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/)

A little time reading is recommended.

Comment: thank you, now i got javascripts snippets for converting php form to xl sheet format from wsnipeets.com                                    http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/